# Twig cache inside if statement

Tags: twig, timber

I'm having following situation where I need to check for global ENV variable (dev || prod)
Using twig v1.x and Timber v1.x

```
{% if is_prod %}
 {% cache 'homepage;#{hash_key};' post %}
{% endif %}
...code
{% if is_prod %}
 {% endcache %}
{% endif %}
```

> *Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Unexpected "endif" tag (expecting closing tag for the "cache" tag*

Is there a workaround for that. tnx

Comment: You can't conditionally cache in twig

Comment: looking at twig cache extensions docs, it mentions Blackhole caching strategy for local development. Have to dig deeper to see.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have two typos here:

```
{% cache 'homepage;#{hash_key};' post %)
```

to

```
{% cache 'homepage;#{hash_key};' post %}
```

and

```
{% endcache '%)
```

to

```
{% endcache %}
```

Comment: it was typo here in SO